# How to keep the stream after a forkJoin or a concatAll(), toArray()

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I am trying, for the sake of learning, to keep the stream after, for instance, a forkjoin. But I would like to do it with pipe (in an elegant way). Not just recover the array, and then rewrite a from(array).subscribe, again.

I tried to do a from, inside the pipe, but that doesn't work. Also I would like to know (as bonus questions) what would be the ideal way, in the pipe (first pipe in this case, because I suposse there will be 2 pipes), to modify each mock_post call result BEFORE the array of the forkJoin is returned.

Just a little mock function that I created to simulate a dummy api return value after 2s.

```
    private mock_post(url: string): Observable<object> {
        return from(timer(2000)).pipe(
            map(result => {
                return {id: 2, name: 'mock', source: url};
            })
        );
    }
```

First test case with ForkJoin (using above function)

```
        const operations = [];
        operations.push(this.mock_post('/api/test/'));
        operations.push(this.mock_post('/api/test/2'));
        operations.push(this.mock_post('/api/test/3'));

        forkJoin(operations).pipe(

        )
            .subscribe(
                (next) => {
                    console.log(next);
                }
            );
```

Second test case with concatAll() + toArray().

```
    const obs: Observable<any> = from(operations);
        obs.pipe(
            map(result => {
                // I want to modify the result here, and add something to the object or modify a property (for example)
                console.log(`result-> `, result); // This is(obviously, returning an observable, but how do I get the final value here?)

                result.name = 'mock_modified';

                return result;
            }),
            concatAll(),
            toArray()
        ).subscribe(
            (next) => {
                console.log(`-> NEXT`, next);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(`* ERROR`, error);
            },
            () => {
                console.log('=) COMPLETE');
            }
        );
```

If anyone can shed some ligth here, it would be great. I hope I explained  myself correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am responding to my own question, after searching more.

(By the way I am using RXJS6.5)

for test1, after a forkjoin, I basically piped a concatMap, and, inside, did a from(result), to emmit each value from the array. Afterwards, mapping each individual result, to just test the change of that returned object and log the result (probably a tap() would have achieved the same if no modification was necessary on the object.

After that, a simple toArray(), will just give me back 1 single array.

```js
    test1() {

        const operations = [];
        operations.push(this.mock_post('/api/test/'));
        operations.push(this.mock_post('/api/test/2'));
        operations.push(this.mock_post('/api/test/3'));

        forkJoin(operations).pipe(
            concatMap((result) => {
                return from(result);
            }),
            map((result: any) => {
                console.log(`resulting-> `, result);
                result.name = 'changed';
                return result;
            }),
            toArray()
        ).subscribe(
            (next) => {
                console.log(next);
            }
        );
    }
```

That said. If anyone has a better way, or an alternative way.

I am all ears.

I am marking this question as answered by myself, because it works (for now) how I want it.

I am still grasping all the concepts of RXJS and trying to keep the stream in an elegant way.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

there is really no need to do array operation with operators. You can just do it in map

```
 forkJoin(operations).pipe(            
            map((results: any) => 
               results.map(result=>({...result,name:'changed}))
),
```